# my computer hard-locks up with heavily threaded disk access

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, raid

short of reformatting, I don't know what to do. It passed both C: and D: NTFS disk error checking (chkdisk at boot).

I recently transitioned my D: data drive from RAID AHCI (BIOS config, though not RAID drives, just using the RAID controller to access) to straight AHCI; but this is happening with heavy C: (as in, different physical drive) access.

It's likely I'll just put up with this if it meant completely reformatting and re-installing everything-- I can get around heavily threaded accesses for the time being.

What else can I look into besides uninstalling and updating or re-installing the AHCI drivers or reformatting? I feel like I've already ruled out all the options. **Is there anything I'm not thinking of?**

Comment: Honestly; Your problem isn't all that clear

Comment: @Ramhound my computer hard-locks up with heavily threaded disk access...

Comment: If this happens with any HDD installed in the system it sounds like a controller problem.  If it happens with just this single HDD that indicates the driver isn't as healthy as you might think it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a completely-stable-overclock with the AMD SB750 SATA controller in RAID mode became partially unstable when set to AHCI mode. removing overclock remedied.

Answer (score 0):

procmon.exe to view the disk thrashing requests and you'll have a better view of the particular thread(s) and applications causing the thrashing.

Things as innocuous as windows indexing, AMD Catalyst Control Center or even some background software patching can insidiously kill performance and can be ruled out before reformatting.

You're well served to ask for last minute advice instead of just assassinating your current installation since you already know you can reformat and reinstall anytime and you likely won't have to.

Procmon is a free Microsoft utility, runs w/o installation and runs on every version of Windows ever made in this century, you'll notice it's tiny and tight and has a toolbar with four icons for viewing Registry, file, network and the Process and Thread calls.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

Disable all except File/Disk (the file cabinet) and the Proc/Thread (Windows Flag) and activate real time scrolling on the x'd out sheet of page to your left and you'll have a real time view of the culprits.

Comment: it's locking up the PC, not slowing it down